# Wordpress. Servidor mysql caído, user o password incorrecto

Tags: wordpress, mariadb, php7

Cuando intento instalar Wordpress me aparece lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo curioso es que sí puedo acceder a mi base de datos (Mariadb). Estoy usando la versión 7 de php sobre Ubuntu 16.04, tendrá algo que ver?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero sus comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa tu archivo `wp-config.php` que se encuentra en la carpeta `public_html` o en la carpeta principal del sitio, en caso de que sea otra. Es la carpeta donde instalaste Wordpress.

Los siguientes valores **deben coincidir exactamente con tus credenciales de conexión a la base de datos** (donde he puesto tres puntos `...` deben ir los valores reales.

```
define('DB_NAME', '...');

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', '...');

/** MySQL database password */
//define('DB_PASSWORD', '...');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '...');

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');

/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Por supuesto, para que Wordpress funcione debe estar correctamente instalado en la base de datos que indiques en esta línea del `wp-config.php`:

`define('DB_NAME', '...');`

Comment: Claro, todo fue ingresado incluso manualmente, todo está en orden, pero igual no se puede instalar. Voy a probar con una conexión independiente.

Comment: @Ricky ¿Cómo que no se puede instalar? no entiendo, se supone que el WP debería estar **instalado correctamente**. ¿Es un Wordpress en local o en un servidor remoto?

Comment: Justamente ese es el problema, que no se puede instalar. Tengo todo configurado, puedo acceder al servidor de bases de datos, puedo ver la base de datos, pero me muestra el error.

Comment: @Ricky Ese mensaje sale por lo general cuando la instalación de WP se ha hecho. ¿Seguro que pusiste las credenciales en el archivo y carpeta correctos? ¿Es un WP local? Me extraña que aparezca una IP con 192.168. ...

Comment: Ya encontré el problema: Era cuestión de asignar permisos al usuario mysql, aparentemente al instalar MariaDB era necesario asignar los permisos también al usuario.

Comment: @Ricky Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto. Puedes responder tú mismo y marcarla como solución o eliminar la pregunta, para que no quede abierta y otros intenten responder cuando ya está resuelto.

Comment: Tienes razón, ya puse la respuesta, creo que podría ser útil para otras personas. Gracias por tu tiempo.

Answer (score 0):

Solucioné el problema. Al final no era un problema de WordPress, sino de permisos del usuario de MySQL, para solucionar el problema era necesario crear un usuario con todos los permisos sobre la base que había yo creado, de esta forma:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'myuser'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Eso es suficiente.